# Biometric ZKTeco SpeedFace V5L [TI]

Tags: zkteco

I am trying to connect to a ZKTeco biometric, Speedface V5 TI model, but I cannot establish a connection between my computer and the biometric, since I need to obtain the user's data every time they register in it, if someone could help me please .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), 
take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, 
post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt

Comment: If you are looking for establishing the communication between the device and the zkteco software, then you need to check with the vendor where you got the software from. If you are looking for connecting with your own server then you need the web API enabled as explained in https://camsunit.com/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html